# How to start / stop a process using a .sh file?

Tags: process, restart

I think my confluence page died and the process stopped working.
I want to restart it, how to do that using these files:

```
start-conlfuence.sh
stop-confluence.sh
```

Google hasn't helped so far, and I tried to simply run the files by entering `start-confluence` or `start-confluence.sh` without success. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the .sh files:

1. give them execute permissions `chmod +x start-conlfuence.sh stop-confluence.sh`
2. to run: `sudo ./start-conlfuence.sh` or `sudo ./stop-confluence.sh`

Or easilu you can just run by the command `sudo sh start-conlfuence.sh` or `sudo sh stop-confluence.sh`